# Counting vowels in a string c#

Tags: c#

I am making a program to analyse features of a user inputted sentence. To count the vowels in the sentence I have made a very messy sequence of foreach loops here:

```
foreach (char v1 in input)
{
    if (v1 == 'a')
    {
        vcounter++;
    }
}
foreach (char v2 in input)
{
    if (v2 == 'e')
    {
        vcounter++;
    }
}
foreach (char v3 in input)
{
    if (v3 == 'i')
    {
        vcounter++;
    }
}
foreach (char v4 in input)
{
    if (v4 == 'o')
    {
        vcounter++;
    }
}
foreach (char v5 in input)
{
    if (v5 == 'u')
    {
        vcounter++;
    }
}
```

I then take the vcounter and display it as the result. I am very new to c# and I am wondering if anyone can suggest a better way of doing this?.

Comment: Hint: consider a dictionary

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Store your vowels in array like this:

```
private readonly char[] vowels = new char[] { 'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u' };
```

And then count them:

```
public int CountVowels(string text)
{
    return text.ToLower().Count(x => vowels.Contains(x));
}
```

Comment: If you create a HashSet instead of an array, it will be faster :) Contains in array is really full scan.

Comment: @IlyaChernomordik for tiny sets full scan might be actually faster. Anyway it's a micro-optimization. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

If your are using .NET 3.5 or higher you could use LINQ for this.

```
vcounter += input.Count(v => v == 'a');
vcounter += input.Count(v => v == 'e');
vcounter += input.Count(v => v == 'i');
vcounter += input.Count(v => v == 'o');
vcounter += input.Count(v => v == 'u');
```

For this you must import LINQ in your document.

```
using System.Linq;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with following code:

```
const string vowels = "aeiou";
var count = input.Count(chr => vowels.Contains(char.ToLower(chr)));
```

or

```
for (int i = 0; i < input.Length; i++)
    {
        if (input[i]  == 'a' || input[i] == 'e' || input[i] == 'i' || input[i] == 'o' || input[i] == 'u')
        {
            count++;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Store your vowels in list :

```
List<Char> vowels = new List<char>() { 'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u' };
```

And count like this :

```
int vcounter = 0;
foreach (char chr in input)
{
   if (vowels.Contains(chr))
   {
       vcounter++;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var text = "hfdaa732ibgedsoju";
var vowels = new[] { 'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u' };
var vowelFrequency = text.Where(c => vowels.Contains(c))
                         .GroupBy(c => c)
                         .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g.Value.Count());
```

Will create a dictionary similar to Maksim's answer but only with vowels.

Use `vowelFrequency.Sum(vf => vf.Value)` to get the total count of vowels in the string.

Answer (score 0):

Not very efficient, but short

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

// ...

var vcounter = Regex.Matches(input, "[aeiou]", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase).Count;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just use a regular expression:

```
vcounter = Regex.Matches(input, "a|e|i|o|u", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase).Count;
```

Comment: you don't need to escape the input. that's only if you are trying to turn a normal string into a match expression.

Comment: Good point! I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can maintain in this function. I created a array which contains some letters.

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string [] array = { "a", "b", "c", "d" };
            int vcounter = 0;
            foreach (var item in array)
            {
                if (item.Contains("a") || item.Contains("e") || item.Contains("i")) //You can add the other volwes 
                {
                    vcounter++;
                }
            }
            MessageBox.Show("Count of vowels : " + vcounter.ToString());
        }
```